# How to run pretrained models of Pixel Objectness

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I can't run pretrained models of **Pixel Objectness** published by Suyog Dutt Jain et al in 2017.

I referred section *Using the pretrained models* in README.md on GitHub, but couldn't understand the following procedures well.

・Setup: Download and install Deeplab-v1 from here

・Refer to demo.py for step-by-step instruction on how to run the code.

I tryed to install and run "demo.py", but I got some errors.
Though I referred solutions on Website, unsolvable error remained.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /mnt/C6BF-F678/pixelobjectness/pixelobjectness-master/demo.py
/usr/local/DL-Box/digits-4.0/caffe/distribute/bin/caffe.bin test --model=/mnt/C6BF-F678/pixelobjectness/pixelobjectness-master/test.prototxt --weights=/mnt/C6BF-F678/pixelobjectness/pixelobjectness-master/pixel_objectness.caffemodel --gpu=0 --iterations=4
I0606 14:34:09.451035  9830 caffe.cpp:261] Use GPU with device ID 0
I0606 14:34:09.451524  9830 caffe.cpp:265] GPU device name: Quadro P6000
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 424:16: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "interp_param".
F0606 14:34:09.811586  9830 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /mnt/C6BF-F678/pixelobjectness/pixelobjectness-master/test.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@     0x7f3829e1cdaa  (unknown)
@     0x7f3829e1cce4  (unknown)
@     0x7f3829e1c6e6  (unknown)
@     0x7f3829e1f687  (unknown)
@     0x7f382a58ef7e  caffe::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
@     0x7f382a5c8418  caffe::Net<>::Net()
@           0x407954  test()
@           0x40625c  main
@     0x7f3828979f45  (unknown)
@           0x406a2d  (unknown)
@              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have installed GPU and caffe.

It is much appreciated if you would explain procedures carefully.

Comment: have you installed `deeplab-v1` correctly? the error you are getting is because `'test.prototxt'` net you are trying to use has a `layer` with `interp_param` - this layer/parameter are NOT part of BVLC/caffe current distribution, and it might be a layer introduced in deeplab-v1.

Comment: Thanks for reply soon.

Comment: I understood why the error occurred. Would you tell me which model I should install from DEEPLAB:MODELS and how I can refer to "demo.py"?

Comment: it's not the model that is problematic, you need `caffe.proto` that has the definitions of the parameters used by the model you are trying to use. It seems like you need `caffe.proto` "shipped" as part of deeplab-v1 caffe. Alternatively, you can find a model that is not using the "undefined" parameters: but these models may not be doing what you expect them to...