# How to use caffe.proto for deeplab to run Pixel Objectness

Tags: github, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I could't run pretrained models of Pixel Objectness published by Suyog Dutt Jain et al in 2017.

I referred to [How to run pretrained models of Pixel Objectness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406188/how-to-run-pretrained-models-of-pixel-objectness), but couldn't find appropriate caffe.proto and don't know how to use it.

How can I run the model by referring to [Pixel Objectness](https://github.com/suyogduttjain/pixelobjectness)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44406188/1714410